# Validating a related object by it's name

Tags: symfony, validation, doctrine-orm

I have a User and Message with one to many relationship.

When creating a form for Message, I would like to have the user field be a string, so that user's name can be entered instead of his id. I added $userName to message class which I do not persist but need to validate it, retrieve the correct id and set the user during form validation. Since using entitymanager in Entities is a bad idea, I thought this validation and user setting should take place in controller.

My question is: How do I set form errors from a controller, and am I doing this right? Any tips?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Note to anyone who might be interested how I did it:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormError;

$field = $form->get('receiverName');
$field = $field->addError(new FormError('User dose not exist'));
```

I do my validation inside a controller and set the error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do like this because if you try to do it with entity field you can have performance problem if you have to many users...
Another solution would be to use a listener on the form...Take a look how Symfony makes the form security token.

To set form errors it's easy : $form->addError(new FormError("Message"));

Regards.
Y